# qTip2: Top/bottom tips not getting correct height/width?

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I've created an example on jsfiddle showing the, here: http://jsfiddle.net/F9bAZ/

Why are the top/bottom tips rendered like that?
The left/right tips are correct.

I've just updated to qTip 2.1.1 and it broke. 2.0.0 worked fine.

Some code:

```
$.fn.qtip.defaults = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.qtip.defaults, {
    style:{
        tip:{
            corner: true,
            width: 24, //This doesn't work for top/bottom tips
            height: 12 //This doesn't work for top/bottom tips
        }
    },
    show: {
        effect: false,
        delay: 1
    },
    hide: {
        effect: false,
        delay: 0
    },
    content: {
        attr: 'data-tooltip' // Tell qTip2 to look inside this attr for it's content
    }
});
```